# Flutter objectbox updating entity

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I have two entities link together, works ok with the putting a new data into the box but if I try to update one of the entity it works ok but I loose the the one I updated anytime I try to query the source object only the that have not been updated comes...

Comment: Please provide your code, so that the issue is reproduceable and your code can be corrected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.